# Android graph view date axis not displaying properly

Tags: android, graph, android-graphview

I have an issue with graphView on android, when i try to display my graph with dates on x axis I got this result:
[graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgijS.png)

The x values are changing each time i generate the graph and the bar in the graph are sometimes displayed, sometime not its really random.

Here is my code:

```
            Cursor weeklySale = db.getWeeklySale(login);

            DataPoint[] dp= new DataPoint[weeklySale.getCount()];
            Date[] dates= new Date[weeklySale.getCount()];

            int i=0;
            while(weeklySale.moveToNext())
            {
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MM yyyy");
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                cal.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, Integer.valueOf(weeklySale.getString(1)));
                cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);

                // Date c = new Date(weeklySale.getLong(1));
                dp[i]= new DataPoint(cal.getTime(), (long)weeklySale.getFloat(0));
                dates[i]= cal.getTime();

                System.out.println(weeklySale.getFloat(0)+" + "+weeklySale.getString(1)+" , "+sdf.format(cal.getTime()));
            }

            graph.removeAllSeries();

            GridLabelRenderer gridLabel = graph.getGridLabelRenderer();
            gridLabel.setHorizontalAxisTitle("Semaine");
            gridLabel.setVerticalAxisTitle("CA");

            LineGraphSeries series = new LineGraphSeries<DataPoint>(dp);
            series.setColor(Color.RED);
            graph.addSeries(series);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try to change the count of labels via:

`graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setNumHorizontalLabels()`

Also you should move this line out of the while loop to save memory and performance:
`SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MM yyyy");`